# I mirrored my character and I have a question

Tags: modeling, animation, sculpting, mirror, sculpt

I have a question about the mirroring, I did a mirroring on my character and the middle part is peeling off in the middle of the mirroring in the division between one side and the other and I'm afraid that this will interfere with the character's animation, how can I change the mirror configuration to join the two sides?

Comment: It would have been nice to show screenshots of this "peeling off" effect and your _Mirror_ modifier configuration. So I can only suspect the "peeling" comes from _Subdivision Surface_ modifier after mirroring and on the _Mirror_ modifier the _Merge_ option is disabled. Ir the vertices on the center line are not close enough together to be merged.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean by "peeling".

If there is space between the mirrored sides, than you probably don't have the origin point in the middle of the model. If you don't know how, you can tab into edit mode, press "a" to select everything and move it, so that the edge of the model (where the mirrored mesh should start) sits on the origin of the object (orange dot).

If there is no space between the mirrored sides than you probably didn't turn on `merge` checkbox in the mirror modifier options.

Also, I don't know what kind of modifiers you have on your model, but you should most likely have the mirror modifier on the top of the modifier stack.

Oh, and if you already applied the mirror modifier, you probably have overlapping vertices. You can merge all the overlapping vertices by tabbing into edit mode, selecting everything with "a", press F3, and type "merge". Select `merge by distance`.

Hope this helps.